# Sequential iteration (Parallel.For())

Tags: c#, parallel.for

The output of this code is different each time. Is it possible to have a sequential output of i (iteration count) from 0 to 21?

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int N = 1000;
            Parallel.For(0, N, (i, loop) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                if (i == 21)
                {
                    loop.Break();
                }
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible - don't use parallel. You either need parallel execution with undefined order or sequential - with defined.

Comment: But if don't use parallel then it will be simple For() loop.

Comment: Parallel will create thread for each iteration and you can not ensure the sequence of execution of threads.

Comment: If I want to execute the first (0-5) five iteration and then the last (17-21) five iterations and then the leftover iterations, how do I do that? a sequential output of 0,1,2,3,4,5,17,18,19,20,21,....the leftover .

Comment: "But if don't use parallel then it will be simple For() loop" --- exactly. That's what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sample with Index**

```
foreach (var obj in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select((s, i) => new {index = i, value = s})
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(obj => new {obj.index, value = obj.value*obj.value, thread=Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})
    .OrderBy(o => o.index))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1} on {2}", obj.index, obj.value, obj.thread);
}
```

Results from a Core i7.

```
0:0 on 1
1:1 on 3
2:4 on 5
3:9 on 1
4:16 on 1
5:25 on 1
6:36 on 1
7:49 on 1
8:64 on 1
9:81 on 1
```

**Sample with a built-in index**

```
foreach (var obj in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
             .AsParallel()
             .AsOrdered()
             .Select((idx,val) => new {idx, value = val*val, thread=Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})
           )
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1} on thread {2}", obj.idx, obj.value, obj.thread);
}
```

Comment: one question, if I do some exactly same operations in each iteration and add the results in an array will the return value of each iteration be ordered too inside the array?

Comment: I'd recommend that you add an ordering index, execute as parallel, than order by that index. It will execute faster.

Comment: Sounds just what I need. Can you help me with a code example? or a link might help to build this code.

Comment: The value of the thread is same in each iteration. R you launching each iteration in one thread each time? ---

Comment: Perhaps your PC has fewer resources than mine ... Mine showed 3-4 different thread IDs. Try with more elements or longer processing per element.

Comment: Yes. Increasing the range to 100 shows 2 different thread ids. ---Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

When the Parallel.For method is used the particular order of execution is not guaranteed. The advantage is the loop completes faster on a computer that has available cores since the steps often take place at the same time, in parallel. You do still have the guarantee that all of the loop’s iterations will have run by the time the loop finishes but not the order in which they will. If you want to run a sequential loop than you should use `for`.

Comment: Thanks. I now its clear that I have no option except using For()